# Watch for changes inside a scope

Tags: angularjs

I have a scope called `$scope.activites` that stores the response data from a service,

```
activitiesService.loadActivities().then(function(response) {
  $scope.activities = response.data;
  console.log ($scope.activities)
})
```

I would like to add a class to a icon in my template when the `$scope.activities` changes.

```
%i.fa.fa-bell{"ui-sref" => "home.activities"
```

And then remove the class when the new activities have been viewed by the user.

I'm thinking I need to use `watch` and look for changes on the activities scope and then perform an action. I tried adding this code to the activities controller,

```
$scope.$watch('activities', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  console.log ('new activity')
})
```

But this just runs everytime I load the activities controller, not just when the scope has changed.

Comment: Why not just have a flag `$scope.activities = response.data; $scope.unread = true;`?

Comment: Could you provide a link to the `flag` documentation? I can't seem to find much about it. And I can't really make much out your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you want to somehow persist a state in your scope (which created by your controller), you can't do it like that.
You'll need a service which will store the current state of your 'activities' array/object.
Then check the object equality when a new activity loaded to check if the 'state' of that object/array has changed or not.